# How many approaches to Torah are there?

Tags: number, torah-study, midrash, parshanut-theory

Our sages tell us that there are שבעים פנים לתורה (Bamidbar Rabbah).  Does this mean that every word, or verse, or some unit, has 70 interpretations, and there are theoretically billions of combinations of explanations of the Torah, or are there 70 approaches to learning the Torah, and each one would yield a single approach to the entire Torah?

Even if one were to take this number to represent it being many, and not an actual number, the question remains: Are the many different approaches to Torah specific to each idea, or are they different approaches of how to view the entire Torah, with one consistent theme or attitude?

Comment: Feel free to edit or add to my tags - I wasn't sure where to put this.

Comment: I'm not sure the _midrash_ is to be taken literally; often numbers like 70 (or 7, 400, 600,000 etc) are used to mean "a lot".

Comment: So let's say it means "many" or pick a number that you really like a lot.  And then re-read the question that way.  But I think there are those who take it literally.

Comment: @YEZ If you think it means a lot then your question fails. "Does it mean a lot, or a LOT?" is essentially what you are asking. So editing in a source for someone who takes the number 70 uber-literally would validate your question greatly

Comment: @Ypnypn +1, moreover, I believe that every Ben-Tora has he's own legitimate viewpoint

Comment: @DoubleAA If it means a lot, then the question would be read "Are there many independent understandings which can be combined, or a smaller "many" which are one approach to the whole Torah" - the question is the same, is it approaches to individual ideas or approaches to Torah as a whole.

Comment: see the shaar gilgulim. which says there are 600,000 root souls (which started as 70 when jews entered egypt) which correspond to the 600,000 channels of the sefirot and the shefa of the torah goes through these 600,000 channels. hence there are 600,000 channels or faces of the torah, but the torah itself is infinite. not that i know what i'm talking about but it's something along those lines.

Comment: @ray I'm not sure if that is related to this question or not.  Did you mean it to be?

Comment: yes, it's all very similar system. all ligned up. the roots of the souls correspond to the interpretations of the torah. just like the 613 human limbs/gidim correspond to the 613 mitzvot.

Comment: @ray it doesn't seem like that is any more indicative of if that is a verse by verse basis or a broader approach, just a different number given

Comment: Possibly related: "R' Yehoshua of Sichnin says in the name of R' Levi, the children who lived in the days of David Hamelech, when they had not yet tasted the flavor of sin, knew how to expound the Torah in **49 ways** that something is tamei and **49 ways** that the same thing is tahor" (Yerushalmi Pe'ah 1).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Osiyos D'Rabbi Akiva](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33180&st=&pgnum=28), it would seem like there's 70 interpretations to each of the sections of Torah (Torah, Nevi'im, Kesuvim, Halachot, etc.):

> עד שלמדו בארבעים ימים כשהיה עומד בהר תורה בשבעים פנים של שבעים לשון, נביאים בשבעים פנים של שבעים לשון, כתובים בשבעים פנים של שבעים לשון, הלכות בשבעים פנים של שבעים לשון, שמועות בשבעים פנים של שבעים לשון, הגדה בשבעים פנים של שבעים לשון, תוספות בשבעים פנים של שבעים לשון.