# Pardes... What actually happened?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tanach, pardes

Verses in the Bible traditionally have four different understandings: Pshat (simple meaning), Remez (derived meaning), Drash (investigative meaning), and Sod (esoteric meaning).

It seems at times that these understandings are at odds with one another, such as in the case of Reuben and Bilah ([Gen. 35](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0135.htm):22). The simple meaning of the verse is quite clear, yet there are opinions, cited by Rashi, that something else happened, that precludes the simple meaning.

When there is a contradiction in intepretation, how does one determine what actually happened?

Comment: Who would care about number 2? That's not Torah.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34870/how-many-approaches-to-torah-are-there

Comment: don't have time to write it up right now, but I know someone gave a shiur on it recently: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/813048/Rabbi_Netanel_Wiederblank/What_actually_happened:_pshat,_drash,_both,_or_neither

Comment: @DoubleAA that seems to be the opinion of Nahmanides!

Comment: http://asif.co.il/?wpfb_dl=2376

Comment: I am pretty sure that that usage of פרדס is merely Zoharic. Rambam for example in Hil. Yesodei Hatorah ch. 1-4 explains it as physics and metaphysics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This summary was written by @BabySeal, not me]

Rabbi Netanel Wiederblank, who teaches Machshava to YU semicha students, [gave a lecture](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/813048/Rabbi_Netanel_Wiederblank/What_actually_happened:_pshat,_drash,_both,_or_neither#) that discussed this very topic. His lectures/shiurim are highly recommended

Pertaining to the question, Rabbi Weiderblank finds two stances among the commentaries:

- [Nissim of Girona](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissim_of_Gerona), [Abraham Ibn Ezra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra), and [Don Isaac Abarbanel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Abrabanel), Rabbi Wiederblank reasons, **take the simple, (pshat), meaning of the text to account for what actually happened.** Ibn Ezra and Abarbanel give reasons for their conclusions, arguing that if noteworthy things mentioned in midrashim actually happened, they should in fact be mentioned in-verse.
- [Nahmanides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahmanides) disagrees openly with Ibn Ezra, and seems to Rabbi
  Wiederblank to be of the opinion that is does not matter what
  actually happened. Nahmanides oftentimes defends both the simple
  meaning and the investigative, (drash), and then moves on, making no
  effort to deliberate further as to what historically happened. This
  attitude can also be found in the Talmud [Yoma 5b](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=yoma&daf=5b&go=Go), (מאי דהוה
  הוה‏, what happened happened). Rabbi Wiederblank also mentions
  Joseph Haim Jerushalmi's book, [Zakhor: Jewish History and Jewish
  Memory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0295975199), that investigates our nation's historical disinterest in
  factual history! According to this view, Rabbi Wiederblank concludes that
  **what happened is indeterminate and irrelevant, as far as Torah is concerned.** Understanding all of Pardes thoroughly , even when it is
  contradictory, articulates the depth of the concept at hand.

In general, the concept of dispute regarding historical matters is discussed by R. Yitzchak Hutner in a letter (published in Iggros Pachad Yitzchak, no. 30). I'll quote the relevant pages, which discuss this issue in context of a dispute regarding the beams of the Mishkan:

> הנה ידוע לך שהיו בישראל כמה וכמה גניזות נגנזו הלוחות נגנז המשכן 
>   נגנז הארון וכו' ובודאי שמכל גניזה היו תוצאות בדרכי התורה ועבודה ומפורש היא הדבר בכתוב בדברי יאשיהו המלך בשעת גניזת הארון שאמר שגניזת הארון הולידה חידוש באופיה של תורה ועבודה והוא הדין והיא המדה בכל הגניזות והנה כשם שאפשר לגנוז חפץ כמו כן אפשר להסתיר ידיעה ועליך לדעת כי בשעה שפלוני אלמוני סובר כי קרשי המשכן נעשו באופן ידוע שונה מכפי שהיתה המציאות באמת הרי זה אינו אלא טועה אבל בשעה שחכם מחכמי המסורה של תשבע"פ שהתורה ניתנה על דעתם ל' הרמב"ן שהם הם אנשי עצתו של יוצר בראשית כשהוא סובר שקרשי המשכן נעשו באופן שונה מכפי שהיתה המציאות באמת הרי אין זה אלא גניזה בכוח הדעת כשם שגוף המשכן נגנז לפי רצונו של מקום כמו כן יש מהלך שגם הידיעות על עלינו ובגינו של משכן ידונו לגניזה אלא שבזמן שמקום גניזתו של גוף המשכן הוא בחללא דעלמא הרי גניזת הידיעה על אודות המשכן הוא בכוח הדעת של חכמי המסורה וממילא במקום שהידיעה על אודות פרט אחד מבנין המשכן נוגעת לנו היום להלכה כגוונא דסוגיא דשבת דקרשים שעליך הנך דן אז אם חכם מחכמי המסורה של תשבע"פ לא כיון אל מציאותו של גוף הבנין הרי דוקא ע"י זה כוון לרצונו של מקום מפני שבאופן זה רצונו של מקום הוא לצרף את גניזת הידיעה לגניזת
>   הגוף וממילא ההלכה היוצאת מסברתו של חכם זה היא היא ההלכה האמיתית וכל מציאות יש לה ואמת שלה וגם המציאות של תורה יש לה אמת משלה והאמת של מציאות תורה הוא הכוון לרצון השם וכששני האמוראים חולקים באופן עשייתם של קרשי המשכן פירוש מחלקותם הוא כיצד נגלתה לפנינו עכשו תמונת קרשי המשכן מפני שההלכה היוצאת מפלוגתא זו אינה תלויה לגמרי במציאותם של קרשי המשכן אלא באופן גילויים גניזת קדשי כנס"י היא היא גופה של תורה מפני שכל גניזה פועלת היא על מהלך חיי הקדושה בישראל ומחלוקת האמוראים היא כיצד עלינו לדרוש את הפסוקים הדנים בענין זה מפני שדרשות הפסוקים אצל חכמי תשבע"פ הוא הוא רצונו של מקום בגילוי ענין זה בכוח הדעת וכל פרט ממציאות גופו של משכן שחכמי תשבע"פ לא מצאו מקום לדרוש אותו מן הכתובים או מן סברתם אינה אלא גניזה וכשיעמוד ב"ד גדול בחכמה ובמנין מן הב"ד הקודם אשר ע"פ דין יש לו כוח לבטל את דברי הב"ד הקודם וידרוש את הפסוקים באופן אחר המהפך את תמונת הענינים מן הקצה אל הקצה אז נאמר כי רצונו של מקום הוא עכשו לגלות את מה שנגנז מקודם ואלו ואלו הם דברי אלקים חיים כמובן שמקומם היחידי של גניזות אלה וגילויים אלה אינם אלא בכוח הדעת של חכמי תשבע"פ לבד כל דעת אחרת הנמצאת בעולם מופקעת היא מכל המהלך הזה של גילוי וגניזה וממילא אין אנו אומרים עליה אלא אחת משתים או שזה טעות או שזה נכון אבל כל סברותיהם דעותיהם ודרשותיהם של חכמי המסורה של תשבע"פ מופקעים הם מעצם ההבחנה של נכון ובלתי נכון ואין אנו מבחינים בזה אלא הופעה של גילוי או הופעה של גניזה אידי ואידי רצונו של מקום הם אלו ואלו דברי א' חיים

Comment: I'm curious as to Rashi's opinion. In the case I cited in the question, for example, he quite simply brings down the mid rash. This could either be like Nahmanides, or a new opinion, evaluating the text and midrashic sources, case by case.

Comment: My impression is that he takes the Ramban's position. He seems totally unconcerned about the fact that he so often quotes more than one opinion and differentiates between peshat and derash

Comment: right, but some times he lists pshat first, sometimes drash… there is no way to conclusively determine anything, but I think you could make an argument that Rashi thinks it depends!

Comment: see this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6103/is-rashi-really-pshat on Rashi's methodology (though oddly none of the answers there quote from Nechama Leibowitz's article on Rashi's methodology, or any of Avraham Grossman's articles, who both have what I think are very convincing views as to how Rashi wrote his commentary)

Comment: a translation or paraphrase of R' Hutner's words would be helpful!