# Categorization of Mepharshim by PaRDeS?

Tags: tanach, commentaries, pardes

I was wondering if anyone has ever come across a classification or categorization of the different mepharshim on the Chumash or Na"Kh, grouping them by the type of perush they give (i.e., whether their derech of elucidation is primarily pshat, remez, drush, or sod). E.g., someone remarked to me once that the Sfas Emes's sefer is giving remez.

If there is no such categorization available, maybe we could propose such a grouping here?

Thanks very much, 
Daniel

Comment: It might be difficult to answer because it's difficult to objectively categorize a book by this criterion, and even if it were possible, every book can have multiple levels (e.g. my first impression tells me that Rashi uses pshat and drash, Ibn Ezra uses pshat and sod, etc.).   See if [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38893/1569) is useful even if it isn't exactly your question. On the site in general see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) and about subjective questions [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Otherwise, this is a very interesting question.

Comment: How about a community wiki answer?  @ba

Comment: Interesting question, and acceptably subjective in my opinion. I think answers will tend to have different groupings, depending on what typology-mapping theory each is using. I would therefore think multiple good answers would each state their theory at the top, and then list the breakdown.

Comment: I think this is too broad because of how many commentaries there are.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a start through community wiki.

- Baal Haturim - remez
- Ibn Ezra - pshat and sod (from ba)
- Malbim - in Vayikra and the halachic parts of Shemos, Bamidbar, and Devarim, his focus is connecting pshat to drash.  In Terumah, Tetzaveh, and Shir Hashirim, he connects pshat to remez.  Elsewhere he's mostly pshat.
- Metzudos (David and Tziyon) - pshat
- Rashi - pshat and drash (from ba)
- Sfas Emes - remez (from Daniel David Slate)