# Parshanut Theory/Intro Books

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, pentateuch-chumash, rishonim, parshanut-theory

I am currently looking for a book that gives a thorough introduction into the Rishonim's and other Meforshim's understanding of the Chumash in their compilations and a guide to Parshanut and (Jewish) bible study in general. Any suggestions?

To be clear, I am not looking for a book that goes through various opinions of  Rishonim etc on particular events recounted in the Torah but for a book which delves into the different approaches/perspectives to dealing with the text and also the different historical and sociological background's of these Rishonim and their approaches to Parshanut.

I know this is not super specific but would be appreciative of any suggestions with a short description. Thanks

Comment: Mikraos Gedolos? :-)

Comment: Everything on alhatorah is fantastic. They offer detailed biographies with a focus on parshanut style, as well as many organized articles that can serve as case studies.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות - the OP says he is looking for a book?

Comment: @Dov that's why it's a comment and not an answer...

Comment: I thought we had this question already but this is the closest I could find https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92329/759

Comment: There is very little available on this topic.

Comment: R. Menachem Kasher had an essay (in Hebrew) going through the major rishonim on parshanut. Can't seem to find it at the moment :(

Comment: Found the essay I mentioned in the previous comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51490&st=&pgnum=296

Answer (score 6):

If you read Hebrew, check out this book. https://korenpub.com/products/parshanei-hamikra

It's an amazing resource.

Comment: Perfect exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Avigayil Rock's book mentioned previously, the series *Masters of the Word* (currently two volumes) by Yonatan Kolatch matches what you are looking for.

Comment: Was going to post this myself, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’ll appreciate this.

https://anchor.fm/misfit-torah/episodes/Is-Creativity-Possible-in-a-Religious-Tradition--The-Paradigm-Busting-Rashbam-e1np8l