# Are there any practical examples of ‘70 faces of the Torah’?

Tags: torah-study

It is [[somewhat] known](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83039/16706) that there are 70 faces to the Torah; that the Torah can be interpreted in many ways, even 70.

Has this rule made its way into the realm of realistic usage, or is it just an exaggerated ideal not meant to be taken literally?

Comment: It is not "well known", it is just an idea that just like other realms divide into 70s like 70 languages, 70 nations (probably the same),  and 70 ways of Torah corresponding to those 70 nations and languages.

Comment: @AlBerko I'd call it "well known"....the rest of your comment doesn't disprove it

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most well-known example of this concept would be the [Tikunei haZohar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikunei_haZohar) (תקוני הזהר).

In this book, the first word of the Bible, בראשית, is expounded on in over 70 ways. For example, בראשית- ברית אש, בראשית- בית ראש.

Additionally, among the literature of [Rabbi Nachman of Breslov](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachman_of_Breslov), he writes that a similar book could be written on each world of the Bible.

Comment: Seems wrong to me. 1. פנים comes from פן which is a "way", an "approach" not just a different interpretation. 2. Also it's 70 ways of Torah, not a word or a verse. There are 70 different (probably hierarchical) ways of interpreteng Torah, like the well known Pshat, Drash, Remez and Sod, so having 70 ways of pshat is not enough.

Comment: Also I think it is rude to come with your own answer before hearing others, it seems you're not interested in the question but publishing your Chiddush.

Comment: In such case, I'd advise to wait until other reply and then add an answer of yours. That will look like you worked on the answer also.

Comment: It happens many time that you don't realise the full magnitude of your question or other considerations, that can change it dramatically.

Comment: @AlBerko https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer